# index.html.erb file template is missing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created an `index.html.erb` in `views` and also I have uncommented `root 'home#index'` in my routes and also there is no index file in public folder.

I am still getting this error:

```
Missing template home/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
Searched in:
  * "C:/ruby/rails/myrubyblog/app/views"
  * "C:/ruby/rails/myrubyblog"
  * "C:/"
```

Rails.root: C:/ruby/rails/myrubyblog

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, since you don't have any other errors that you do have a `home_controller`.

So, the only thing missing is to put the `index.html.erb` into a `home` folder. (`app/views/home/index/html.erb`)

Comment: yes i have put index.html.erb file in views/ home ..i even tried renaming file  and then making changes in methods and routes.. but its still not able to connect to views..not able to understand what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Changing 'application' to 'default' in line 5 and line 6 of layouts/application.html.erb solved my problem.

this happens in windows

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an inconsistency in the controller class name and the corresponding folder name in your views directory. Maybe you have something like

```
HomesController or HomeController
```

and in the views directory, you have:

```
home or homes
```

as the case may be. It is also possible that you have a typo in the spelling of the index file.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Rails on Windows try the answer from user352974:
 (Changing 'application' to 'default' in line 5 and line 6 of layouts/application.html.erb )

It totally works, besides that, on your browser address bar, try this url: http://localhost:3000/pages/home

Where /pages/ is the folder that contains the page you want to show (that is, your index) and 'home' in my example is my index, which is located here: C:\Sites\YourProjectFolderName\app\views\pages\home.html.erb

Comment: To user Laurel: 
You can also score by editing a simple word in an answer? Like  the word "Cheers!"? Cool! I'm new to S.O so I haven't gone through all the rules yet, would you please be so kind to explain why my word "Cheers" was inappropriate in my post? Thanks!